# ajax call is not working even after tried many solutions

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I tried many solutions but still, the ajax call is not working.
It's not showing console errors or any bug. I tried $_POST and $_REQUEST

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="usernamee" class="col-sm-2">Select Customer :</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <select class="form-control select2" required="" name="uid" id="customer_name">
      <?php
        $getcust = $conn->query("SELECT id,full_name FROM `data_entry`");
        while ($fetch1 = $getcust->fetch_array()) {
      ?>
      <option value="<?=$fetch1[0]?>"><?=$fetch1[1]?></option>
      <?php  } ?>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Ajax Call**

```
$("#customer_name").change(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var idd = $('#customer_name').find(":selected").val();
      var data = 'idd=' + $('#customer_name').find(":selected").val();
      //alert(data)
      $.ajax({
          type : "POST",
          url : "ajax_get_subid.php",
          //data : {idd:idd},
          data : data,
          success : function(data) {
              alert(data);
          }
      });
      e.preventDefault();
    });
```

The ajax call is inside `$(document).ready(function(){()}`. Jquery Version is 2.2.3

**And PHP**

```
<?php

if(isset($_REQUEST['idd'])){

    $id = $_REQUEST['idd'];

    echo $id;

}

?>
```

And In My File JS Are

```
<script src="../plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="../plugins/input-image-display/fileinput.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../dist/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $.widget.bridge('uibutton', $.ui.button);
</script>
<script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../plugins/select2/select2.full.min.js"></script>
<script src="../dist/js/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="../plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<script src="../plugins/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="../plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="../plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="../plugins/fastclick/fastclick.js"></script>
<script src="../dist/js/app.min.js"></script>
<script src="../dist/js/demo.js"></script>
```

is it conflict ?

Comment: what do you mean by *not working*?

Comment: Explain _not working_

Comment: No console Error No Alert

Comment: Post your HTML snippet, as far as I can see there is only thing which could go wrong, that's the posted data which is undefined..

Comment: Do you load the `#customer_name`  dynamically? Can you show the `#customer_name` portion in your code?

Comment: You need to check whether the AJAX call is getting fired? If yes, what's the response?

Comment: Also, calling `e.preventDefault();` once is enough..

Comment: `var_dump($_REQUEST)` in php to check you're getting the values

Comment: Check the network tab on the console

Comment: Put an alert inside the `.change` functionality before ajax. You can check whether the function is calling or not

Comment: in the google chromes developer tools go to Network tab and you'll see if there is any request , if there is no requests then  you have to check your js code.

Comment: @Boratzan  i Tried That too. And also Posted Html code

Comment: @MilanChheda How Can i check is ajax fire or not. because i tried to put alert before ajax so it is working but in ajax it not

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile You didn't see my comment. No Console Errors Will Generate

Comment: Open developer tools, Go to Network, Check if request is fired or not.

Comment: i tried this. No Request is fired

Comment: Have you tried this mini code: $("#customer_name").change(function(e) { alert('hi'); });

Comment: So that you will know whether it goes into condition or not

Comment: @web-infos what u get in var data & var idd of ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

its could be more easier if you use $.getJSON or $.get/$.post and in this case I think $.getJSON is a best option especially for future code changes.

***JS Code:***
*/scripts/main.js*

```
function getData(requestID, callback){
    $.getJSON("/api/getData.php",{id:requestID},callback);
}

function customerName_change(){
  debugger;
  getData(12345,function(result){
     debugger;
     console.log(result);
     alert(result.ID);
  });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#customer_name').on('change',customerName_change);
});
```

***Php Code:*** 
*/api/getData.php*

```
<?php
  class ApiResult {
     public $ID;
     public $Extra;
  }

  $res = new ApiResult();
  $res->ID = 234124;
  $res->Extra =$_REQUEST['id'];

  echo json_encode($res);

?>
```

Comment: @WebInfos add a breakpoint into customerName function in chrome developer tools, and one question , is customer_name a TextBox (input[type=text])?

Comment: `return false` is `stopPropagation` **and** `preventDefault` and not only `stopPropagation`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `select2`, you need to use it like this:

```
$("#customer_name").on('select2:select', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var selectedVal = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax_get_subid.php",
    data: {idd: selectedVal},
    success: function(response) {
      alert(response);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: No Response By ajax .

Comment: You need to share complete information. Did you check console for errors? Did you check network for whether request was fired? Did you try adding `alert()` in this code to debug?

Comment: Please Check Comments. i give all details. I tried Everything. No Console Errors And in network Tab There is no Request Found When I Change Select Box Variable

Comment: I have updated my answer. Realized that you are using `select2` and not the default HMTL `select`. You can try the updated code.

Comment: Thanks. But Sorry Not Working.!

Comment: I would recommend to check the documentation for `select2`: https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events#listening-for-events

Comment: I Tried That Too And Also I try By Removing Select2 . Select2 Does not matter because i get id With or Without Select2 But The problem is in Ajax Call

Answer (score 0):

bro i think you missed the dataType in ajax call try this i hope this will help you:

```
$("#customer_name").change(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
    var id = $('#customer_name').find(":selected").val();

    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "ajax_get_subid.php",
        data : {id:id},
        dataType:'json',
        success : function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

And your PHP to:

```
 if(isset($_POST['id'])){

   $id = $_POST['id'];

   echo json_encode($id);

}
```

Comment: Thanks. But Sorry Not Working.!

Comment: No Console Error No Changes And Nothing at all. I checked network Tab no response is there

Comment: ow i see you jquery doesnt run well. maybe it is conflict did you try to remove your other js for a while just for testing purposes?